# Eloquent relation insert/create with grand parent id

Tags: laravel, eloquent

There are three model.

```php
class GrandParent extends Model
{
}
```

```php
class Parent extends Model
{
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Child::class);
    }
    public function grand_parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(GrandParent::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class Child extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['parent_id','grand_parent_id','data'];
}
```

When insert a record into Child, the parent_id and grand_parent_id also insert, but grand_parent_id is manually given

```php
$data = $this->someDataGenerator();
$child = Child::first();
$child()->create([
    'grand_parent_id' => $parent->grand_parent->id, //manually insert
    'data' => $data
]);
```

Is there a way do it by Model? So whenever `$child()->create($data)`, the **grand_parent_id** would automatically insert?

Comment: Isn't the grand_parent implicit in the parent? Dont you know it's grand_parent_id by knowing its parent_id parent?

Comment: i think what you want is a nested set, here is a plugin you can use if that is that case, https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset, but if not then you can just listen to the `created` event of the Child Model and attach the parent's parent's id there

Comment: @namelivia thanks for remind, I've modified my question:)

Comment: I still don't know what do you need `grand_parent_id` for on your `Children` class if you can access it navigating through `Parent` and that is automatically set.

Comment: @namelivia sometimes one of the Parent or GrandParent record may be deleted, so we think to keep parent_id and grand_parent_id inside Child may provide some information.

Comment: You could use SoftDeletes for Parents and GrandParents? That way the record would appear as deleted but the link wouldn't be lost and you could keep referential integrity.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add `grand_parent_id` to the Child table.
if need gets a GrandParent of GrandParent:

```
$child = Child::find(1);
$grand_parent = $child->parent->grand_parent;
```

and get all children from GrandParent model by using Has Many Through relationship:

```
class GrandParent extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the grandchildren for the GrandParent.
     */
    public function grandchildren()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Child', 'App\Parent');
    }
}
```